# How to place text on certain part of a window Tkinter

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I want to place certain text I get from an API on the pokedex image.

```
import tkinter

from PIL import ImageTk, Image


im = Image.open(r'pokedex.png')

root = tkinter.Tk()


tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)

b = tkinter.Label(root, image=tkimage, text="Hello", compound=tkinter.CENTER).pack() # Put it in the display window


root.mainloop() # Start the GUI
```

Currently I have this but I want to add more text on other parts of the image. How do  I place a new text on X and Y coordinates?

Comment: Did you read any documentation before asking the question?

Comment: @BryanOakley I have read the documentation about PIL and tkinter. The major problem is that I can't get another label on the image it self. Only under the image.

Comment: use [Canvas](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm)